# Adding Custom input view to UITextField in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, inputview

I am trying to use a calculator as a custom input view to an UITextField in swift.

I have a calculator separately defined in my app as CalculatorViewController.

I need to access the CalculatorViewController in the UITextField I have in my InputViewController.

I defined the following property in the InputViewController to access the calculator view

```
var textFieldInputView : UIView!{

        let calculatorInputController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("calculatorVC") as! calculatorViewController

        let calculatorInputView = calculatorInputController.view

        return calculatorInputView
}
```

then added following code in the textField to access the textFieldInputView

```
    textField.inputView = textFieldInputView
```

Now when I click the textField, the calculator popup,as per the below, which is not in the position where keyboard appears. Also none of the buttons working.

Much appreciated if some one could advise me how to get this fixed.

[image: screenshot of custom input view]

Answer (score 3):

Resolved this as per the below.

1. Created a interface builder "**keyboard.xib**" with all the `UIButton` and `UILabel` for display.
2. Linked the `keyboard.xib` to `calculatorViewController`
3. Subclass the view controller (say `DetailViewController`) where the `UITextFields` are present as the subclass of `calculatorViewController`.
4. Created a `UIView` as per the below code

   ```
       var customkeyboardView : UIView {

       let nib = UINib(nibName: "CalculatorView", bundle: nil)
       let objects = nib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)
       let cView = objects[0] as! UIView
       return cView
   }
   ```
5. Assign the customkeyboardView as an inputView of the UITextField as indicated below

   ```
   textField.inputView = customkeyboardView
   ```